# NetSuite: How to disable "new" button on a linked record in netsuite using suitescript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

We have customer records in NetSuite CRM module with additional custom records linked to the customer record. We have a custom field on customer record "customer status".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjl6x.png)

Based on customer status we want to disable new custom record (in this case new service record) button. I am able to use beforeLoad script to disable button on main customer record but similar approach fails when I try to disable button associated with linked record.

```html
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.0
* @NScriptType UserEventScript
*/
define(["N/log", "N/ui/serverWidget"], function(log,ui) {
    function disableNewCaseButton(context){
        if (context.type == context.UserEventType.VIEW){
            var customerStatus = context.newRecord.getValue({"fieldId" : "custentitycustomer_status"});
        if (customerStatus !== 1){
            var newButton = context.form.getButton({
                id: 'newrecrecmachcustrecordso_customer_name'
            })
            try{
            newButton.isDisabled = true;
        }
        catch(e){
            log.debug({
                title : "error",
                details: e
            });
        }

        }
        return;
    }
}
    return {
        beforeLoad: disableNewCaseButton
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any API supported way to do this.

If you want to resort to DOM hackery, you could use a client script to hide it:

```
document.getElementById("newrecrecmachcustrecordso_customer_name").style.display = "none";
```

Keep in mind that there is no guarantee this won't break in a future NetSuite updates.

Another approach could be to leave the button, but use a Workflow or Script on the linked record to prevent it from saving if the customer status is not valid.

Comment: Preventing the record from being saved works, but it is not elegant as the user may have already typed up the information (we are trying to do this for support/case module).  By manipulating the DOM I was able to disable the button, there is no "view' event for client script so it fails to produce the desired effect.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3757527 You can't deploy a client script in view mode, but if you use a User Event to set the client script it will run in view mode as well. You could also inject client script into view mode via a Custom Inline HTML field.

Comment: can you provide some guidance on how do I use user event script to set client script? Do I use user event before load event inject a client script?

Comment: @irfans Correct. You just need to set `context.form.clientScriptModulePath` or `context.form.clientScriptFileId` properties with the client script path / internalid

Comment: Try creating an On Entry workflow to check if the customer status is valid, if not, workflow diverts the user somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Set the custom record Access Type=Use Permission List. Then on the Role configuration, assign the custom record permission to the Role with Access=View.

View access is lower than Create so the user with this role will be able to select but the “New” option will not be available in the dropdown selection.